# How to turn Template has_many questions into a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

User story: User can create a Template. Each template `has_many` questions. User `has_many` templates. Template and Question `belongs_to` user.

Right now the user can create questions for a template. User clicks on template and they see a list of questions.

Problem:

How do i turn this into a form where the user can answer the questions. The user needs to be able to use the template and infinite amount of times. A user must be able to click what template they want to use then fill out the form.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is a bit vague, it sounds like you need to set up a couple tables to hold answers to your questions, which also belong to a user. I would recommend a table to hold a reference to all responses for a given template: i.e. `belongs_to :user, :template`. Then, create a table to hold answers to each question, maybe called `answers`? Each row would belong to a `user` and `question` and thus a given 'template' with a `through:` option set on a `has_many` association. Does that make sense?